# Suspend/Resume a thread or process from another Thread in different process

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

In one of my projects I create multiple processes (which are sub projects that I developed) from my main project as **CREATE_SUSPENDED** and storing their handles in a global array but; when I want to resume it with *ResumeThread* function I get **ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE** error code.

[The MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-resumethread) specifies that the thread must have THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME access right and I couldn't find how to set it.

Do those handles are only valid on its process space and how can I suspend/resume a thread or process from another process with all the handles I stored?

Note: I know synchronization objects may have a use here but is it the only and only way?

One more issue is; how to obtain handle of a thread created by my ProcessClass from the main process, which also created that ProcessClass?

Here is a portion of the code

ProcessClass

```
void ProcessClass::Start(){       
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);

    BOOL createdProc = CreateProcess(NULL, 
        ProcessExeDir, 
        NULL, 
        NULL, 
        TRUE, 
        CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE | CREATE_SUSPENDED
        , NULL, 
        NULL, 
        &si, 
        &pi); 
    if (createdProc == FALSE)
    {
        UINT32 errorCode = GetLastError();        
    }
    else
    {
        DWORD affinity;
        affinity = 0x000000010 << (5);
        SetProcessAffinityMask(pi.hProcess, affinity);

        ProcessHandler = pi.hProcess;
        ProcessInfoPtr->ProcHandle = ProcessHandler;

        // I can need this handle
        // CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    }
}

// ProcessInPtr is defines as ProcessInfoStc* in the header
ProcessInfoStc* ProcessClass::GetProcessInfoPtr() {
    return ProcessInfoPtr;
}
```

In the Main Project:

```
int main() {
   // this is declared as ManageProcesses(const ProcessInfoStcPtr& processes)
    ManageProcesses(ProcessInfoArray);
    return 0;
}
```

In ManageProcess function which is in the same lib project with the ProcessClass and following structure definitions:

```
ProcessClass processObj = new ProcessClass();
processObj->Start();
...
HANDLE pHandle = processObj->GetProcessInfoPtr()->ProcHandle;
//! pHandle is is same with the created process handle as I debug
ResumeThread(pHandle); 
DWORD error = GetLastError(); // RETURNS INVALID HANDLE
```

And the Structure to store process is also in main process

```
ProcessInfoStc {
    HANDLE ProcHandle ,
    DWORD ProcId..
 }
 ProcessInfoStc ProcessInfoArray[10] = {
     {
        0,0...
     },...
 }
 typedef ProcessInfoStc* ProcessInfoStcPtr;
```

Comment: I think some code sample might be useful.

Comment: Since the the code was very straight forward using documented CreateProcess - CreateThread and Suspend/ResumeThread functions I din't write it here. Maybe the thing I want is impossible.

Comment: of course error in your code. but invisible without code. handles of process/thread returned in `PROCESS_INFORMATION` of course valid, until you not close it. and you can suspend/resume thread by it handle. you or close handle, or bad store it. or use process handle instead thread

Comment: If you don't want to show any code then we can just close the question

Comment: `ResumeThread` require **thread** handle, but you pass to it **process** handle. of course error, as i guest at begin *or use process handle instead thread*

Comment: You are not checking the return value of `ResumeThread()` for error. Calling `GetLastError()` afterwards is only meaningful if `ResumeThread()` returns -1, otherwise you get a *stale* error code from a *previous* API operation. But indeed, you are actually passing the wrong handle to `ResumeThread()`. It expects a **thread** handle (`pi.hThread`), but you are passing it a **process** handle instead (`pi.hProcess`). You can't resume a process, only a thread. Update `ProcessInfoStc` to store both `HANDLE`s (and don't forget to close both of them when you are done using them)

Comment: @RbMm yes that was the reason, the developer before me was closing the handle but; the process can still be working by calling Resume in its own code. How this could happen? A handle can be reopened?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - *You can't resume a process, only a thread* - possible and all threads in process suspend or resume in single call `NtResumeProcess` and `NtSuspendProcess`. so possible call `NtResumeProcess(pi.hProcess)` instead `ResumeThread(pi.hThread)`, but of course need use correct handles

Comment: *A handle can be reopened?* - for what ? if it need - not close it.

Comment: @RbMm fine, I'll amend my earlier comment - "*You can't resume a process **with `ResumeThread()`**, only a thread*".

Answer (score 2):

> In one of my projects I create multiple processes (which are sub projects that I developed) from my main project as `CREATE_SUSPENDED` and storing their handles in a global array but; when I want to resume it with `ResumeThread` function I get `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` error code.

That is because you are passing a **process** handle (`pi.hProcess`) to `ResumeThread()`.  You cannot resume a **process** using `ResumeThread()`.  As its name implies, you need to pass it a **thread** handle instead (`pi.hThread`).

> The MSDN specifies that the thread must have `THREAD_SUSPEND_RESUME` access right and I couldn't find how to set it.

You already have it, per the documentation:

[Creating Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/procthread/creating-processes)

> The thread and process handles are created with **full access rights**, although access can be restricted if you specify security descriptors.
>
> how to obtain handle of a thread created by my `ProcessClass` from the main process, which also created that `ProcessClass`?

You are not currently storing the thread handle anywhere, you do can't retrieve it.  Update your `ProcessInfoStc` struct to store both `HANDLE`s that `CreateProcess()` returns.  And don't forget to close both of them when you are done using them.

Comment: as alternative solution possible call `NtResumeProcess(hProcess)` on stored process handle, instead store thread handle and call `ResumeThread(hThread)`. also if use `NTSTATUS` error codes - `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` instead `GetLastError()` here - situation became more clear at begin - `ResumeThread` on valid, but not thread handle will return `STATUS_OBJECT_TYPE_MISMATCH` which clear enough. but win32 convert this status to the same value as `STATUS_INVALID_HANDLE` - `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE` - as result valuable information about error is lost. this is typical for win32 errors

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend against stopping/resuming threads using the OS or threading library low level APIs, unless you are writing a thread scheduling algorithm (but then your code should reside in the kernel). In a modern OS and correctly written multi-threaded application threads in a waiting state consume almost no resources, so there should really be no reason to intervene there. That would be the reason why you will unlikely see `thread.suspend()` and `thread.resume()` in practical code examples nowdays.

I would just build an application the way that threads would be polling (via an abstraction of IOLoop, Dispatcher, Executor, Actor, etc.) on IO selector(s), task queue(s), and only wake up and do something when there's a work to be done.

Comment: Did you forget about debuggers? Probably the most common reason to want to suspend a thread.

Comment: Agree on that, but I doubt it’s the most common reason of asking how to suspend a thread though.